# Doctrine does not see my custom Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I'm new to Symfony/Doctrine. I've create an entity "Merchant" based on a table I had created. It worked perfectly.

Now I've created an entity "Provider" and would like to generate the table for it.

I've used doctrine:mapping:import and it only imports the Merchant one. The Provider is nowhere to be found.

Thanks!

Edit : I've tried using "shema:update" but it returns "Nothing to update - Your database is already in sync".

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your "Provider" class "name" or "namespace" is right and also do't forget to use

```
        use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

if your entity class is in the annotation format ..
Sometimes may be it's file name is "Provide" rather than "Provider.php" and may be class name is not as per its namespace or also you have forgotten to use namespace ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying create database schema based on your entities you should use different command.

Following one will drop and create the schema (pay attention that this will remove all your database data):

```
app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force
app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

Or you can just update existing schema:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

In addition to above command you can just look at sql changes that doctrine is going to apply to your db, without applying them:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

Comment: I edited my answer to reply to you : when using update --force, I receive "Nothing to update"

Comment: Try this: 1) remove your database 2) create an empty database 3) run doctrine:schema:create command. Now you should have your entites and db schema sync. If there is still the table missing then maybe you missed something in your entity (like for example you didn't add appropriate annotations)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database config file has your database name that matches your Entity's schema name.

If they are mismatched, no differences are notec, no SQL gets created

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem. Console restart worked for me.